# CSS transition only one transform function

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

Is there a way to animate only one transform function? For example i only want my transition on scale function. How will i do this

```
.my-class {
    transition: transform;
}
.large {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
}
```

---

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class large"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what you did. (plus vendor prefixes and transition time) What didn't work?

Comment: @bjb568 what i acctually want was not to include rotate on my transition since his on transform property. my goal is only scale function on transform property will animate. help

Comment: Oh, then I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you like to transform only the class .large ?

Comment: @Prasanth yes. but only the scale will animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your code a little and YES you can. Just assign the different transform functions to different classes and use only those classes that you want...like so.

Importantly `DO NOT FORGET` to use the respective `browser supported engines` when using animations to make it work. Here is a list of various browsers supporting various animation features.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/support/

```
.my-class {
    transition: transform;
}

.scale_and_rotate {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);    
}

.scale_class {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); // Safari and Chrome(Engine:-Webkit)
    -moz-transform: scale(2); // Mozilla(Engine:-Gecko)
    -ms-transform: scale(2); // IE(Engine:-Trident)
    -o-transform: scale(2); // Opera(Engine:-Presto)
}


.rotate_class {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

and finally you can apply these classes depending on your requirements

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class scale_class"></div> // only scale function
<div class="my-class rotate_class"></div> // only rotate function
<div class="my-class scale_and_rotate"></div> // both scale and rotate function
```

Check the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/plsbugmenot/9b5YF/)

If you want to scale and rotate together then the class given by you should work.
And also you can look into CSS `@keyframes` to achieve this. Here are few good tutorials

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/

Comment: do you have tried this code on your browser? i think the "both scale and rotate" div is: rotate_class will just override the scale_class' transform property. the scale function will not be executed because it's overridden by the rotate function. sorry i know i cant explain will but i hope you get my point

Comment: Oopsie, I forgot to add a class. Have edited the changes just check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plsbugmenot/9b5YF/)  for complete code

Comment: Sorry i also forgot to set the transition value to [transform 2s] and sorry again because I'm not so specific on explaining what i want. Now my main point was for example i have a div with no class and i have a script that will place a class(scale_and_rotate) on it then i only want the transition transform 2 sec on scale function there will be no animation on rotate

Comment: Ok then can you please update the question accordingly now so that others can help you out too

Comment: And also can you create a fiddle to explain your problem better